# R: importing data impossible (windows)

Tags: r, csv

I used to work with R on my mac and never had any problems.

Now I would like to use it on my work computer (windows). The problem is I can't import any files to start working with them. I tried several options:

```
mydata<-read.table("c:/temp/myfile.csv",header=TRUE)
mydata<-read.csv("myfile.csv",header=TRUE)
mydata<-read.table("c:/myfile.csv",header=TRUE)
mydata<-read.table("Desktop/myfile.csv",header=TRUE)
```

I also tried to change / into \ in all variants above.

Nothing seems to work. R displays the command in red, sometimes with a comment "connection can't be opened" or "no such file or directory" (my translation from German).

I tried copying the file I want to open to a different location (desktop, c:, temp), but alas, nothing helps.

Do you have any ideas why I have this problem and how I can solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set the right working directory?

Comment: Try `getwd()` to check your working directory.

Comment: `R` is case sensitive, are you sure your hard disk is called `c:` and not `C:`?

Comment: I tried. But when I write: setwd("C:\temp"), the message is "error in setwd("C:\temp"), working directory cant be changed"

Comment: Try `setwd("C:/temp")`, no backslashes in `R`, even if Windows likes 'em.

Comment: Use / or \\, not \

Comment: Thanks, but the result of setwd("C:/temp") is still the command in red.

Comment: Not trying to sound like the common tech support, but did you check if your hard drive is called `C:` and not anything else? It could even be a network device. What does `getwd()` tell you?

Comment: Follow these steps: 1) set your working directory using `setwd(...)` - it will just return the script line of `setwd(...)`. You can use `getwd()` to check if everything is normal. 2) Put your file in this working directory. 3) Import your file using `read.csv(...)`

Comment: Please show where your files are located. We can only guess at this point.

Comment: Not as a final solution, try `mydata<-read.table(file.choose(), header=TRUE)`. After selecting the CSV file, if you still get a 'file not found' or 'connection cannot be opened', something is wrong with your file system. Either you do not have permissions to the file, the file might be not what you think, or something entirely different, but outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a safer way to work with paths; just using `file.path()`.
So, if you're trying to get a file in C:/temp/turtles.csv, then you'd use:

```
targetFile <- file.path('C:/', 'temp', 'turtles.csv')
read.csv( targetFile, header=TRUE )
```

Minor point since it showed up on Twitter; **DO NOT USE PATHS THAT EXIST ONLY IN YOUR ENVIRONMENT**.
Try to keep the data in a path either in or directly under where the script is.

Answer (score 0):

You have three ways to do this with read.csv() function

1. To avoid inserting actual path you can do it simply nesting function

> read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE)

it will open pop up for selecting your file just select file from directory 
  where you have saved it.

2. Now if you have to insert a path then just get actual location of your file 
   by

   > read.csv("C:\path\to\your\file\filename.csv",header=TRUE)

   for Example

   > read.csv("C:\Users\Amway\Desktop\resources.csv",header=TRUE)
3. Best way is to have your own work space directory
   so create a directory by your preferred name and just set that directory as a 
   R session work space by

> setwd("C:\path\to\your\workspace directory\")

check your current directory by

> getwd()

now if you want to read a file into R session just copy your file to work 
  space and just write

> read.csv("resources.csv",header=TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

So, it should be like this.

```
setwd("c:/mydir")  # note / instead of \ in windows
```

Also.

```
MyData <- read.csv(file="c:/mydir/TheDataIWantToReadIn.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Windows uses the other backslash.

https://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/